# Como localizar cursor na TextBox?

Tags: vba, excel-vba, posição-do-cursor

Olá! Preciso saber a posição do cursor na TextBox quando o usuário digita algum caractere (adicionar uma palavra nessa posição, caso o caractere seja esteja dentro das condições aplicadas no resto do programa).
Tem como eu obter essa informação no VBA?

Obrigada desde já!